# how to use the variable x to initialize an array? i know we cant use variable here

Tags: c, arrays, size

```
#include<conio.h> 
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{   
    int x=10;
    int a[x]={1,2}; //how to use this x and not get an error
    getch();
}
```

How to use this x and not get an error? Initialization needs a constant number so how can this be done?
My problem is the value of x is returned by a function and i want to use that value as the size of my array. and i know i cant initialize the array size with a variable

Comment: what error message are you getting? Please edit it into your question.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish; do you want an array a that can hold 10 objects where indexes 0 and 1 have the values 1 and 2? Or are you wanting an array that has {1,2} at index 10? Or something else?

Comment: yes actually my problem is the value of x is returned by a function and i want to use that value as the size of my array. and i know i cant initialize the array size with a variable.

Answer (score 1):

In C89 you cannot specify the length of an array with a non-constant integer expression (variables do not qualify as constant expressions). You need to use a compiler version that supports C99  and variable-length arrays.

in C89, what you can do is use a macro:

```
#define X 10
```

or use `malloc` to dynamically allocate your array:

```
int *a = malloc(x * sizeof *a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable length arrays are added in C99. Compile code in C99 mode. Use `-std=c99`.

---

**Note:** Looking at `conio.h`, I guess that you are using Turbo C++. Its an obsolete compiler. Update your self.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int x=10;
> int a[x]={1,2}; //how to use this x and not get an error
> ```

You can't.

You can do one of the following:

1. Declare the array size using a *constant expression* whose value is known at compile time<sup>1</sup>:

   ```
   #define N 10
   ...
   int a[N]={1,2};
   ```

   Note that this implicitly initializes `a[2]` through `a[9]` to 0.

   ---

   Use a *variable-length array*, which is only available for C99 compilers and *optional* for C2011 compilers:

   ```
   int x = 10;
   int a[x];   // only valid if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L and __STDC_NO_VLA__ is not defined
   a[0] = 1;
   a[1] = 2;
   ...
   ```

   You cannot use an array initializer like `{1,2}` for variable-length arrays; you either have to initialize the elements individually, as above, or you could attempt to use `memcpy` with a *compound literal*:

   ```
   memcpy( a, (int[]){1, 2}, sizeof (int[]){1, 2} );
   ```

   Unlike method 1, this will *not* implicitly initialize `a[2]` through `a[9]` to 0; those elements will be *indeterminate*.

   ---

   If VLAs are not available (you're using a C89 or earlier compiler, or a C2011 compiler that defines the macro `__STDC_NO_VLA__`), then dynamically allocate space for an array and initialize as you would for a VLA:

   ```
   int x = 10;
   int *a = malloc( sizeof *a * x );
   if ( a )
   {
     a[0] = 1;
     a[1] = 2; // or memcpy( a, (int[]){1,2}, sizeof (int[]){1,2} );
   }
   ```

   Like the VLA method above, this does *not* initialize elements `a[2]` through `a[9]` to 0.  

   Remember to `free` the memory when you're done with it:

   ```
   free( a );
   ```

---

<sup>1. Meaning a literal like `10`, an expression made up of literals like `5+5`, or a macro that expands to one of the previous.</sup>